# Problems in finding urls from the application template in Django

Tags: python, django, templates

Here is the full map of my Poll application:

**My Project/**

```
Poll_app/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
polls/
     migrations/
               __init__.py
               0001_initial.py
     templates/
              polls/
                   detail.html
                   index.html
                   results.html
     __init__.py
     admin.py
     models.py
     tests.py
     urls.py
     views.py

db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

Here, are the codes inside my files:

**Poll_app/settings.py:**

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = 't@o_s8#^88go6lx9haux#b^p%&g63r)03ai!9cw7dm%h#2mjy^'

DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Poll_app.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Poll_app.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
       'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
 }
}
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**Poll_app/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
                   url(r'^admin', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   )
```

**polls/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from polls.models import Poll

admin.site.register(Poll)
```

**polls/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**polls/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   # ex: /polls/
                   url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
                   # ex: /polls/5/
                   url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
                   # ex: /polls/5/results/
                   url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
                   # ex: /polls/5/vote/
                   url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
                   )
```

**polls/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


from polls.models import Choice, Poll

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, poll_id):
    try:
       poll = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
    except Poll.DoesNotExist:
       raise Http404
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'poll':poll})

def results(request, poll_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'poll': poll})

def vote(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    try:
       selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
       # Redisplay the poll voting form.
       return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

**My templates:**

**polls/templates/polls/detail.html:**

```
<<h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{choice.id }}" />
<label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

**polls/templates/polls/index.html:**

```
{% if latest_poll_list %}
<ul>
 {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
     <li><a href="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/"{{ poll.question }}></a></li>
 {% endfor %}
 </ul>
{% else %}
 <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

**polls/templates/polls/results.html:**

```
<h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' poll.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

I have run my app like following:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

When i visit (from localhost) **../polls/results**, the page shows the message **The requested URL /polls/results was not found on this server.**

I am having same result for **..../polls/votes** also.

**N.B.**

While i access **..../polls/** i see a 'dot' only.

I am stuck here from yesterday. I have tried to rebuild the app for 2 times. And yet, still getting the same result again and again. May be, there are spelling errors or problems in setting the **Poll_app/settings.py**. It would be really helpful for me, if you help me to figure out the problem.

Comment: Try visiting `localhost:port/polls/some_poll_id/results` cause that's what your `urls.py` specifies; you don't have `r'^results/$'` specified in your `urls.py`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in polls/urls.py, your regexp pattern only catches those urls of form "../polls/some_number/results" but you are trying "../polls/results" which will not be catched. In the regexp try replacing `+` with `*` and then try to access the url like this `^(?P<poll_id>\d*)/results/$`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check your urls settings.

```
# ex: /polls/5/results/
url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
# ex: /polls/5/vote/
url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote')
```

so you should visit `localhost:port/polls/poll_id/results`